# Asp.net System.Web.UI.Page object in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, object, instantiation

How do I instantiate the asp.net System.Web.UI.Page object in MVC3? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to instantiate the *System.Web.UI.Page* class in an ASP.NET MVC application. There are simply better ways to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: well can you please enlighten me what I should do. I have a custom server control(inherits from page) which I run in MVC3.

Comment: @user742276, use should not any use user controls in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. They simply don't work due to their dependency on classic WebForms notions such as PostBack and ViewState which no longer exist in MVC. You will have to rewrite those controls or find alternatives which are adapted to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm using a third party payment system that needs page as argument